# How to understand this eclipse MAT data?

Tags: eclipse-mat

[show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r2ec.png)
the sum of all node is 399MB, but the every node is small, how to understand ???
（This is a java application memory hprof snapshot, a screenshot of using eclipse mat for memory analysis）

How to understand this eclipse MAT data?

Answer (score 0):

The image shows that the ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] array @0x7a411fdb0 retains 399MB of objects, but the path to those objects goes through two or more of the ConcurrentHashMap$Node objects, so none of the ConcurrentHashMap$Node objects is individually responsible for the retaining the 399MB of objects.

See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/concepts/shallowretainedheap.html?cp=55_2_2

Try on ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] @0x7a411fdb0

- Java Basics > Open in Dominator Tree
- Show Retained Set

to see more.

Also, try running the Leak Suspects report.